# Exclude @SpringBootApplication

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have 2 mains in my project

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan(value = com.somepackage,
            excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = Class2.class)})
    public Class1
```

and

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan(value = com.somepackage,
            excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = Class1.class)})
    public Class2
```

They are both in the same package, but need to scan some other packages.

When I run in my IDE Class1 I don't want Class2 to be loaded and when I run Class2 I don't want Class1 to be loaded.

Doing these exclusion doesn't work and doing `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = Class2.class)` display this error: The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes

How can I exclude the other SpringBootApplication class ?

EDIT:
We are using 2 main classes because we want to have some tools (little scripts) and reuse some part of the code. Example: I have the main class of the application but I want to run some part of it with another main to do some cleanup but very rarely and don't want to setup a lot of libs just to do this. I know it's not clean, but I want to write some main rapidly to invoke my application with all the other bean loaded but not with the first main because it starts a lot of other thread that I don't need.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do these two classes need to be in the same package?

Comment: The SpringBootApplication is a meta annotation that does component scanning and a lot of other stuff incl. component scanning. Detailing why your project has two main application classes might lead to a better and more maintainable answer  e.g. is it conditional config? different beans being loaded etc?

Comment: I added some explanation

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change you application structure to minimal 3 modules:

1. Core code and resources (shared logic)
2. Application 1 code and resources  (use the core module)
3. Application 2 code and resources  (use the core module)

That makes thing easier and more clear. In the application modules you can implement interfaces or extends basic/default configuration from the core.

With this approach you don't have to use complex include/exclude logic for specific classes in you application main classes.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that's the best way to do it. I'll try to do it that way, but I'm still wondering if there's a way to do it because I don't have control  on if I can refactor it in module or not ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could work with profiles using whatever name makes sense for your case.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Profile("!test")
public Class1 {}

@SpringBootApplication
@Profile("test")
public Class2 {}
```

Comment: This is imo the best option since different deployments are usually tied to maven profiles. It solved a use case of mine where I needed a jar and war deployment on the same project and couldn't move packages around.